# How do I source a private repo in a ruby gemfile?

Tags: ruby

My gemfile looks like this:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'capistrano-fiftyfive', :require => false, :github => '55minutes/capistrano-fiftyfive', :branch => :master
```

If I want to add another gem from a different repo that's a private repo, how do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example using [Gemfury](https://gemfury.com/l/gem-server):

```
source 'https://api_token@@repo.fury.io/username'
source 'https://rubygems.org'
```

Don't forget insert proper Gemfury API Token.